# Running Rscript in Bash on Windows

Tags: r, bash

I'm writing a Git hook which should run some R code. If the hook starts with

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
```

then the following code is correctly interpreted as R.

However, `Rscript` looks for my installed packages in my home directory. According to the [R for Windows FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#What-are-HOME-and-working-directories_003f), the home directory is defined by the environment variables `R_USER` or `HOME`. However, the Git Bash shell does not contain either of these, so the home directory defaults to the working directory.

The hook, therefore, fails to locate any non-base packages.

The solution I've found is to create an R file and then use Bash in the hook to call Rscript after manually defining `R_USER`:

```
#!/bin/sh

R_USER="my/home/directory"
export R_USER

Rscript foo.R
```

(Where `foo.R` is in the project's working directory, in this case).

This works but is somewhat inelegant. I'd rather simply use Rscript in the hook itself.

So I considered setting the home directory within the Rscript:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
Sys.setenv(R_USER = "my/home/directory")
```

But while that does set `R_USER`, it doesn't fix the problem. I assume this means that R defines the package-finding path before the script itself is run, so defining `R_USER` within the script doesn't change the fact that it's still looking for packages in the working directory instead.

So, is there a solution to this (for example, by setting R_USER and then somehow telling R to update the package directory)? Or is the use-Bash-to-call-Rscript method the way to go?